# Typescript error 2769 - Trying to pass a process information to data state to use it on a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i'm trying to pass a process to a setData state from a .map function so i can show it on a modal and it is given the following error:

"No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial | undefined; color?: "inherit" | ... 8 more ... | undefined; ... 5 more ...; viewBox?: string | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
Property 'component' is missing in type '{ onClick: void; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType; }'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>): Element', gave the following error.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.  TS2769"

The code is the following:

```
import { Box, Modal } from "@mui/material";
import React, { FC, Fragment, useState } from "react";
import LaunchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Launch";
interface Props {
  setProcesses: (val: any) => void;
  processes: Array<any>;
}
const CourseTable: FC<Props> = ({ processes, setProcesses }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>();

  const handleOpen = (process: any) => {
    setData(process);
    setOpen(true);
    console.log(data);
  };

  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  const diferenceDates = (value: any) => {
    const dateNow = new Date();
    const dateCreation = new Date(`${value}`);
    const diffTime = Math.abs(dateNow.valueOf() - dateCreation.valueOf());
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return diffDays;
  };

  const dateVisitTrimmed = (value: any) => {
    const visitDate = new Date(value);
    const dateVisit = visitDate.toLocaleDateString();
    return dateVisit;
  };

  return (
    <div className='coursetable'>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>N/Ref</th>
            <th>V/Ref</th>
            <th>Proponente</th>
            <th>Contacto</th>
            <th>Morada</th>
            <th>Visita</th>
            <th>Dias em Curso</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {processes.map((process: any) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{process.processNumber}</td>
              <td>{process.vRef}</td>
              <td>{process.clientName}</td>
              <td>{process.clientContact}</td>
              <td>{process.address}</td>
              <td>{dateVisitTrimmed(process.visitDate)}</td>
              <td>{diferenceDates(process.creationDate)}</td>
              <td>
                <LaunchIcon onClick={handleOpen(process)} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Box>cenas da vida</Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CourseTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
<LaunchIcon onClick={handleOpen(process)} />
```

is the issue. The `onClick` prop of a component should be a *function*, but what you have given it is instead the *result of `handleOpen`*, rather than the `handleOpen` function itself.

To fix this, wrap your click handler into an anonymous function which can provide the correct `process` via its closure:

```
<LaunchIcon onClick={() => handleOpen(process)} />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now :D 
I forgot to try it that way as well.